# Textarea allows to enter only one character on IOS. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, html-framework-7

I use Framework7 with Cordova. The problem is that I can not enter the text in the textarea completely. It only happens on IOS (on the simulator and on a real device).

When text is entered from the keyboard, only the first character of the entered text is displayed in the textarea

[image: screenshot 1]

If hide the keyboard and show it again, the first character of the entered text is placed ahead of the previous text. But again only the first character is placed in the textarea

[image: screenshot 2]

And this is the markup of page with textarea:

```
<template>
<div class="page" data-name="feedback" style="background-color:white;" >
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner" id="fb-navbar-inner">
            <div class="left">
                <a href="#" class="link back">
                    <i class="material-icons md-only md-24 md-light">arrow_back</i>
                    <i class="f7-icons ios-menu-color ios-only">chevron_left</i>
                    <span class="ios-only" style="color: white">{{words.back}}</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="title ios-menu-color">{{words.title}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ios-only preloader color-blue" id="fb-preloader-ios" style="visibility: hidden; display: none"></div>
    <div class="md-only preloader color-blue" id="fb-preloader-md" style="visibility: hidden; display: none"></div>

    <div class = "page-content" style="overflow-x: hidden">
        <div align="center"><i class="icon make-feedback"></i></div>
        <div align="center" id="hello" class="ios-menu-color-purple size-20 centered-text" style="margin: -20px 4% 0px 4%">{{words.hello}}</div>
        <div class="list" style="margin: 3% 4% 3% 4%">
            <ul>
                <li class="item-content item-input">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-input-wrap md-only input-purple-theme" id="fb-input-wrap">
                            <textarea id="feedbackText"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-input-wrap ios-only">
                            <textarea id="feedbackText"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="color-gray size-16" style="margin: 0% 4% 0% 4%">{{words.notify}}</div>
        <a class="button button-fill purple-theme" style="width: 40%; margin: 8% 30% 0% 30%" id="sendFB">{{words.send}}</a>
    </div>
</div></template>
```

Maybe someone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It wasn't possible to edit the fields in the form.
The website was using some JS functions and CSS properties to prevent copying. (*

```
ondragstart = "return false" 
  onselectstart = "return false" 
  oncontextmenu = "return false" 
  onselect = "document.selection.empty()" 
  oncopy = "document.selection.empty()"
  onselectstart = "(e) => {e.preventDefault()}"
```

*) and (*

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    
        user-select: none; 
   -webkit-user-select: none; 
   -khtml-user-select: none; 
   -moz-user-select: none; 
   -ms-user-select: none;
```

- ).

**Removing all this fixed everything.**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this isn't an answer that you can solve. It's just a bug with the latest Safari update. For now, you can just try

```
<input type="text">
```

Otherwise, just wait a week (more like a month knowing Apple) to wait for Safari to update and it should.

Comment: I resolved that. In the index.css file I have rules that prohibit text selection throughout the application:

*
{
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

It is not allowed to enter text in textarea. To resolve this problem, I added:

textarea{
    -webkit-user-select: text !important;
    -khtml-user-select: text !important;
    -moz-user-select: text !important;
    -ms-user-select: text !important;
    user-select: text !important;
}

in index.css

Comment: credit to  @ОлесяЕгорова *:not(textarea,input) {}  did indeed fix the issue.  Just modified to use :not operator.